# if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write an if/else statement that will hide my `.thumb` `<div>`s whenever the "about" or "contact" links are clicked. I want all of the `.thumb` `<div>`s to slide up.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/UITabs15.html

I don't have much experience writing if/else statementsI cant seem to figure out the right syntax any help you can give would be much appreciated.

```
        $(function(){
    $('.thumb').hide();

    $('.subnav').click(function(){
        var $menuelement = $('.thumb').eq($(this).closest("li").index());//find the matching nth element in the menu
        if($menuelement.hasClass('active')){//if clicked element is already expanded

            $menuelement.removeClass('active').slideUp();//remove the active class and hide it

        } else {//otherwise,clicked element is not already expanded...

        if ($('.active').length>0) {//...but another element is expanded
            $('.active').removeClass('active').slideUp( function(){
                $menuelement.addClass('active').slideDown();//add the active class and show it
            });

            } else {//another element is not expanded

            $menuelement.addClass('active').slideDown();//add the active class and show it

            }
        }
    });

    });
```

Comment: Please post your source code into the question!

Comment: Can you add some of the code you've tried to your question?

Comment: "I don't have much experience writing if/else statementsI cant seem to figure out the right syntax"  Probably worth getting a book on javascript.   You're not going to get very far in a programming career if you're unable to use if statements!

Comment: Im not a programmer, just a guy tinkering around on the interwebs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try this because it's a bit orphaned, but try the following (or at least the following idea). I was confused because your link didn't actually include the code you posted. Try posting a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the code if you're still having problems.

Your ($('.active').length>0) statement doesn't need the >0 part - all no-zero lengths will return true.

```
    $(function(){
        $('.thumb').hide();
        $('.subnav').click(function(){
            var menuelement = $('.thumb').eq($(this).closest("li").index());//find the matching nth element in the menu
            $(menuelement).toggleClass('active').slideToggle();
            $('.active').not(menuelement).removeClass('active').slideUp();
        });
});
```